# Symfony2: composer exception - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev requires tobie/ua-parser dev- master -> no matching package found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

This is my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.4.1",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.0",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.1",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.0",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.3.10",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.4",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.4.1",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.4",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.4",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "2.1.0",
    "tobie/ua-parser": "dev-master"
},
{
    ...
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
}
```

However, when i run composer install, it is throwing the following errors:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>      - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev -> s
>   atisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.4.x-dev].
>      - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev requires tobie/ua-parser dev-
>   master -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>   - A typo in the package name
>   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
>   imum-stability setting
>     see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion f
>   or more details.
>
> Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common
>   problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution:**

The latest stable release ([0.3.2](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/tree/v0.3.2)) that uses [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) for the `tobie/ua-parser` library was tagged [a long time ago](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/releases/tag/v0.3.2).

This old release didn't include a *composer.json*.

Therefore the package `tobie/ua-parser` doesn't have a **stable** version on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/tobie/ua-parser).

You can install the package by adding the **`@dev`** [stability flag](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links).

```
composer require 'tobie/ua-parser:*@dev'
composer update 'tobie/ua-parser'
```

---

**tip:**

You should change your global `minimum-stability` back to **stable** and *only* add stability-flags to certain packages that you *really* need in a bleeding-edge version!

Setting the global minimum stability to `dev` is a bad practice and can easily break your application.

Change it to:

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
```

... or at least include the `prefer-stable` option in your *composer.json*.

```
"prefer-stable": true
```